# How to make fixed background from regular DIV

Tags: html, css

we all know the css background-attachment: fixed; but I have DIV with class logo as a background and overlay above it and I'd like to make the DIV with logo to behave the same way like IMG with background-attachment: fixed. Is it even possible? Thank you :)

```
<section class="s2">
<div class="logo">
    <h1 class="logom">M</h1>
    <h1 class="logov">V</h1>
</div>
<div class="overlay">
    <div class="over over1">
        <img src="img/ops.jpg" alt="example">
        <p>Example</p>
    </div>
    <div class="over over2"></div>
    <div class="over over3">
        <p>Example</p>
        <img src="img/ops.jpg" alt="example">
    </div>
    <div class="over over4"></div>
    <div class="over over5">
        <img src="img/ops.jpg" alt="example">
        <p>Example</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```css
.logo{ position:absolute}
```

if you want the logo to be fixed ;
*also you can use flexbox  it may give you more opportunities on the place of the logo : if you want it to be at the start the middleor  or the end

```css
.logo{
display:flex;
justify-contient:flex-start/* you can use also flex-end to put the logo on the end or center to be at the center of this div*/}
```

Comment: yes I tried fixed and absolute, so it's fixed in connection with z-index: -1 in my case, thanks